# How to identify and check if transformer is working fine?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, dc

I have 3 in 1 SMD rework station and in that Machine veriable DC power supply is not working and I am unable to check if transformer is working correctly or not and if I have to replace how to find similar transformer because I don't know the name. It has two wire on one side and eight wire on another side. Here are image of transformer if some one will help me to identify and let me know to check it that you will be great help

[image: two wire]
[image: eight wire]

Edit :-
I checked the voltage(AC) and measured as in the below image and It seems that white wire is not giving 12v power and if I short white and purple the it seems that power supply is working but all the voltage at out are different from what it suppose to be. 
[image]

Comment: Transformers don't often fail, I'd put money on the fault being elsewhere. Use your DMM on the AC volts range to measure the output voltage of the transformer where it goes into the variable power supply.

Comment: Yes transformer don't fail often but the circuit is very simple I checked food and capacitor the only thing that left is resistor , transformer and non that select different voltage value . Resistor looks good visually do didn't check according to me there is possibility of fault is in transformer or in voltage select nob.